# Check for if condition JSP and run js function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, if-statement

I am trying to use if JSP condition inside JavaScript function which is initiated onload in JSP site but i am obviously doing it wrong. I am trying to check for URL parameter and only actulary run function when parameter is found. Here is my code.

```
<script language="javascript">

function raj(){

 <%if (String "contact"=request.getParameter("contact");) %>{


    <% String str=request.getParameter("video"); %>
    var s="<%=str%>";
    alert(s);
    }
}

</script>
```

It is obviously syntax problem but i'm just beginning with JSP.

Comment: Though I don't know JSP (Only javascript and other programming language), as a programmer I think there should not be a semi colom after `("contact")<here>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a variable in `if` statement. First create a variable then initialize and check it. Don't forget to close `if` block with `}`.

```
<script language="javascript">

function raj(){   
 <%String contact; if ((contact=request.getParameter("contact")) != null) %>{    
    <% String str=request.getParameter("video"); %>
    var s="<%=str%>";
    alert(s);
 <%}%>
}

</script>
```